# Memory Leak / ContextInjectionFactory / IEclipseContext

Tags: java, dependency-injection, rcp, e4

I am using dependency injection (DI) inside an Eclipse RCP application. I have a lot of classes that perform code similar to below:

```
public class SomeClass {
    @Inject
    private IEclipseContext context;

    private SomeObject void someMethod(){
        SomeObject someObject =
            ContextInjectionFactory.make(SomeObject.class, context);
        // Do stuff with someObject
    }
 }
```

When I monitor the application using jvisualvm, I notice there is a memory leak due to this.  The EclipseContext object keeps growing until it eventually runs out of memory.

If I do the following, the memory leak goes away:

```
public class SomeClass {
    @Inject
    private IEclipseContext context;

    private SomeObject void someMethod(){
        IEclipseContext childContext = context.createChild();
        SomeObject someObject =
            ContextInjectionFactory.make(SomeObject.class, childContext);
        childContext.dispose();
        // Do stuff with someObject
    }
 }
```

I have not seen any documentation that supports doing my workaround.  Is there any negative side effects to disposing the childContext after the class is created?  Is there a better approach overall when using CIF that I haven't encountered?

For what it's worth, my code has many classes, some of which are annotated with @Singleton / @Creatable. I'm not sure if these would be effected by a disposed parent context.

Thanks!

Comment: I haven't seen any reports of there being a leak and I haven't seen this in my code.

Comment: Yeah it's definitely strange. The only difference in my code is what is shown above.  I create a lot of objects, most of which get destroyed when no longer needed. Over the course of a few days I notice there are millions of object refernces in the main context and it grows until I get a memory error. If I do the workaround all is well. Would you know of any negative impact using the workaround?

Comment: If anything you make with the child context injects IEclipeContext it will end up accessing a disposed context if it tries to access it later on. This gives difficult to debug errors. Do you know which field in the EclipseContext class is storing all these references?

Comment: It appears (using Eclipse Memory Analyzer tool) that there are millions of TrackableComputationExt and ContextInjectionListener items under the main EclipseContext.

Comment: "originatingContext org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt" and "context org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.ContextObjectSupplier$ContextInjectionListener"

Comment: OK, I think those are used to track objects injected in to the class that may change and would need to be reinjected.

Comment: It looks like they are all coming from the activeComputations Map and weakListeners object inside the EclipseContext. I'm not sure I understand your last comment. How would I resolve my memory issue based on your comment?

Comment: Added an answer describing what my testing shows is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use injection to set fields in your class like this:

```
public class Test
{
  @Inject
  private StatusReporter rep;
  @Inject
  private IEventBroker broker;


  public Test()
  {
  }
}
```

Eclipse must track each field that has been injected so that it can reinject the field if the value in the Eclipse Context changes. This involves creating `TrackableComputationEx‌​t` and `‌​ContextInjectionList‌​ener` objects for each injected field.

If instead you inject the values in the constructor like this:

```
public class Test
{
  private StatusReporter rep;
  private IEventBroker broker;

  @Inject
  public Test(StatusReporter rep, IEventBroker broker)
  {
    this.rep = rep;
    this.broker = broker;
  }
}
```

Eclipse has no need to track Constructor injection so these objects are not created (but you also won't get any updates if the context values are changed).

Testing this there does still seem to be one internal use tracking object created.

Comment: That's odd that nobody else mentioned the same thing I did since I see a lot of code using field injections vs constructor injections.  Do the tracking objects go away after the class is no longer used? If I have a Collection<Test> objects and clear the collection, do the tracking references go away?  I'm guessing (by the number of instances I've seen) that with field injections they do not (even though I'd expect them to)

Comment: Well Java doesn't have a way of tracking when something 'goes away' (unless there are some WeakReferences somewhere I have missed) so probably not. They probably hang around until the context is disposed. But this code is very complex and hard to read (as usual). I think most people are only using injection on a limited number of UI objects so haven't hit this.